# MongoDB 3.2 $ifNull with Validator

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to achieve a document validator that checks if a user signs up with an avatar to their user profile. If they didn't attach an avatar I want to use something like `$ifNull` to set the default image:

`db.runCommand({
   collMod: "User",
   validator: { $or: [ 
       { avatar: { $ifNull: [ "$avatar", "default-avatar.png"] } } 
    ]},
   validationLevel: "strict"
})`

However, it seems like MongoDB separates document validation and it's aggregation methods... Is there a way to do this so that it will stay as a rule on a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, right now this kind of "validation" is not possible in the mongodb. However, there is [feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24430) open for such feature. If you give your 'vote' for it, maybe they make this feature. ;-)

Currently, the easiest way to archive that is do check (like that) in your application, just before inserting (or updating) document.

Comment: Gotcha, I ended up implementing cloud code for this hook. definitely voted for next round of features, fingers crossed!